# Accumulating [State s a] results

Tags: haskell, typeclass, accumulate

**What I did**

I found myself writing some kind of "renderer", where at some point I had a list of state-transitions:

```
[State String [a]]
```

I wanted to apply them one after the other. I could do this with `sequence`, which brought me to

```
State String [[a]]
```

Then I had to flatten the result from list-of-lists to just list. I could do that by fmapping `concat` and ended up with the desired result

```
State String [a]
```

---

**So far, so good**

But to make this work, my results had to be lists . Shouldn't that also work with a more general type, like a `Traversable`, a `Foldable` or even just a `Monoid`.

I understand, that I ended up with a *list* of results because I started with a *list* of state-transitions and sequence preserves that shape. So, if I take that as given, my first question is

- How do I convert `State String [a]` into `State String a`

My second question is

- can this be generalized even further, such that my input does not have to be a list, but can be of a more general type like a `Traversable`?.

---

**Or, in short**

- How do I apply a collection of state-transitions one after the other while accumulating the results? What are the minimal type-constraints on the type of the collection and the type of the result?

Comment: Note that `sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)` applies to more than lists.

Comment: `accumulate :: (Traversable t, Monad m, Monoid a) => t (m a) -> m a; accumulate = fmap fold . sequence`. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

GHC 8.6+ provide another way of doing this, which is possibly more direct.  It added a newtype, [`Ap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap), to `Data.Monoid` that handles the case of lifting the inner type's `Monoid` instance over an `Applicative` context.

```
$ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import Data.Monoid
Prelude Data.Monoid> :t getAp . foldMap Ap
getAp . foldMap Ap
  :: (Foldable t, Applicative f, Monoid a) => t (f a) -> f a
```

This generalizes `[State String [a]] -> State String [a]` in a pretty minimal form. In fact, by avoiding `sequence` this drops the `Traversable` requirement down to `Foldable`. (The `Monad` constraint on `sequence` is a historical artifact, and `sequenceA` exists to lower that to `Applicative`, so I'm not concerned with the difference there.) This approach has an additional minor operational difference over using `sequence` - it combines both the monoidal joining and the applicative sequencing into a single pass.  There will be some combinations of types where that is more efficient, and combinations of types where it can be less efficient due to associativity.  It depends on whether `mappend` has an associativity bias that fits the bias `foldMap` creates.

Comment: so, as an illustration, `getAp $ foldMap Ap [p,q,r] = liftA2 (<>) p (liftA2 (<>) q (liftA2 (<>) r (pure mempty))) = liftA2 (<>) p (liftA2 (<>) q r)`? so is the combining essentially binary here?

Comment: @WillNess At the `Applicative` level, it has to be binary.  As it makes one pass, the `Monoid` combinations have to be binary as well.  Changing my efficiency notes to emphasize that this might be better or worse, depending on the associativity in the Foldable instance and how well it matches up with properties of `mappend`.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I convert `State String [a]` into `State String a`

Since `State s` is a `Functor`, that question is equivalent to asking: *How do I convert `[a]` into `a`?*

You can use [mconcat](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mconcat) for that.

In order to apply that to `State`, you can combine `fmap` with `mconcat`.

> can this be generalized even further, such that my input does not have to be a list, but can be of a more general type like a `Traversable`?.

Yes, again, the core question is how to turn any container `t a` into `a`. You don't need `Traversable` for that; `Foldable` will do. Particularly, the function in question is [fold](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold).

Again, combine `fold` with `fmap` to achieve the desired result.

Comment: For the sake of completeness it's `accumulate = fmap fold . sequence` and it can be used as `accumulate x` where `x :: [State String [a]]`.